# html-Why does Safari change the webpage background when the devtools are turned on?

Tags: css, safari, webkit, safari-web-inspector

Why does Safari change the webpage background when the devtools are turned on? I've noticed this in Safari Version 10.1 (12603.1.30.0.34) on Sierra ver 10.12.4. What's funny is that I can't reproduce it on another site. Is there something

Comment: Can you post some screenshots of that behavior?

Comment: Ehm, "another site" you say? We need to look at the evidence then. Links to the problematic site and the other site.